# Unusual Apache2 Error Causing Wordpress Redirect Error?

Tags: redirect, localhost

I have the following error in my apache2 error log(Ubuntu 18.04, local LAMP dev environment), that I believe is causing a `The page isn’t redirecting properly` error:

```
[:error] [pid ] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("localhost") failed: Invalid host name
```

I have been searching online for a few hours, but have not found anyway to resolve this error.

The contents of my /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.0.1   localhost.example.org   *.localhost.example.org
127.0.0.1   someothername.org   www.someothername.org
127.0.0.1   blog.localhost.example.org
127.0.0.1   seminar.localhost.example.org
    

#The line below is for shared folder access. DP Edit.
127.0.0.1   machinename.local
```

To ensure that the error is NOT being caused by wordpress, I have tried the following:

1. disabled all plugins = redirecting error still present NOTE: no new htaccess was generated by wp
2. used db query to update siteurl value to match localhost `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='https://localhost.example.org' WHERE option_name='siteurl'` = redirecting error still present
3. updated wp-config  to reflect define('WP_HOME','https://localhost.example.org');
   define('WP_SITEURL','https://localhost.exmple.org');
4. I also tried creating a simplified htaccess file according to [these instructions](https://www.beginwp.com/fix-error-403-forbidden-access-denied-wp-admin-login-page/) = redirection error still present

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect you have an Apache config problem, rather than WP. Have you tried asking over in Webmasters as well? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip... will try there... banging my head on a wall... 3 weeks. :-(